# Appending unique elements to elements with the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where there are a bunch of `<div>` with the same class name.  I need to append unique data to each one of them, but they are only defined by the class.

Example:

```
<div class='test'></div>
<div class='test'></div>
<div class='test'></div>
<div class='test'></div>
```

Is there a way I can scroll through them and append unique data to them using JQuery's append?

Comment: What about this? `$( '.test' ).each( function( index, element ){
    /* do stuff here */
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is put a sample for you where easy div have separate value you can modify it as you need

```js
$(function(){
    var m=1;
    $('.test').each(function(){
        $(this).html(m++);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'></div>
<div class='test'></div>
<div class='test'></div>
<div class='test'></div>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine the difference for these elements, other than looping through the elements and use the index value (so, the ordinal value). Something like:

```js
var nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

for (var i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i += 1) {
  nodelist[i].textContent = 'element '+i;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
<div class='test'></div>
<div class='test'></div>
<div class='test'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach using jQuery `html(fn)`

```
var data = ['text #1','some other text','I am #3','Last <strong>one</strong>'];

$('.test').html(function(i){
   return data[i];
});
```

Alternatively if you are adding to or modifying existing content, the second argument is that content

```
   $('.test').html(function(i, existingHtml){
      return existingHtml + data[i];
   });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nbd8df1o/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: And the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function. Apparently [`.append(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-function) works very similarly (but without clearing the contents of the elements).